# How to debug missing inbound Twilio SMS message requests

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there a way to debug/troubleshoot a situation where a specific phone number is sending SMS messages to a registered Twilio-purchased/Twilio-managed phone number, but those inbound message requests are nowhere to be found in the Programming Messaging Logs (https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/sms)? The issue is not that there's an error, but simply, that the record of that number having sent a message is entirely missing.

The configuration is correct because other phone numbers are successfully sending to the Twilio-managed number, and the record of those sends exist in the logs. It's just this one specific number that has sent multiple messages, but Twilio is saying that the number has never done so, according to Twilio's logs.

Comment: Anything unusual about the sender? Different country? Unusual telecom provider? Any chance the receiving number has issued a "stop" to the sender? If you control the sender, I'd suggest opening a ticket with the sender and tell them that text messages to the receiver are not being received.

Comment: The sender is a US number, has a common telecom provider, and the receiver has not issued a "stop" to the sender. I do not own the sender unfortunately, so all I have are reports of this situation

Comment: Hmmm...Sorry, I am not sure what to suggest at this point. The sender should have a delivery failed if the message didn't go through. With no delivery fail it should show in the Twilio logs. Another thing to double-check is the sender is sending to the correct phone number and doesn't have a digit inverted or wrong.